# Make Folium map interactible from page where it's embedded

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, folium

I'm working on an app that uses ReactJS for front end.

I'm using Folium to generate different kind of maps (choropleth / heatmap / markercluster).

My goal is to be able to control some features of the map from the other components of the app (for instance highlighting markers or area when they're selected in a form).

I first tried to retrieve the map id in my app's main JS code, but I realised that Folium renders maps into iframes which prevents to add any interactivity with the rest of the app.
I hoped I it was possible to render Folium map outside a Branca figure which seems to add the iframe, but it doesn't seem to work and would be just an ugly hack anyway.

I guess I'm not the first willing to achieve something like this, but I was unable to find any solution.

How could I achieve what I'm trying to do ? Thanks.

Comment: I am also looking to do this

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've done it, but it's bloody hideous.

```js
document.getElementById('testBtn').onclick= () => {
    // Get the 'window' object of the iFrame
    const mapWindow = document.getElementById('mapFrame').contentWindow;
    let keys = Object.keys(mapWindow);

    // Folium seems to generate a random code for the map object, so I just
    // looked for a property of the window object starting with 'map_'
    let mapObjKey = keys.filter( name => name.startsWith("map_"))[0];
    const mapObj = mapWindow[mapObjKey];
    mapObj.zoomIn();
};
```

You can then use all the Leaflet methods.